# Generic types comparison

Tags: c#, generics, comparison

I have two objects of generic type T.

```
T x , T y
```

I want to be able to do comparison like:

```
if (x >= y)
```

Therefore I try to use the `compareTo` method which is missing until I add the constraint `where T:IComparable`. Only then I see it in the intellisence.

Not sure why only then I see it and not before writing it.

Comment: Why would you expect to see it before writing it?

Comment: Because that method exists in that interface and you explicitly tell the compiler that your generic types implement that interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Not sure why only then I see it and not before writing it.

Because until that constraint exists, the compiler has no idea what members are available on `T`, other than those which are present as part of `object`. You wouldn't expect to be able to write:

```
object x = GetObjectFromSomewhere();
object y = GetObjectFromSomewhere();
int comparison = x.CompareTo(y);
```

would you? C# is a statically typed language (aside from `dynamic`) - the compiler has to know which members you're talking about when you use them.

As an aside, if the types you're interested in implement `IComparable<T>` rather than just the non-generic `IComparable`, that would be a better constraint. It performs better (because it can avoid boxing) and it's more type-safe (as it prevents you from trying to compare unrelated types).

Comment: Great answer, but how is the option of writing (x as IComparable).compareTo  compared versus the constraint version we already talked about?

Comment: @JavaSa: That option has no compile-time type safety. Heck, using `as` instead of a cast even gives you a bad error (`NullReferenceException` instead of the more sensible `InvalidCastException`). I prefer to use generics to enhance compile-time type safety.